# ASP.NET MVC Validation errors not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-ajax

I am using `tuples` to load multiple models into a view.

The view is as

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, null, ajaxOptions, new { @class = "contact-form" }))

        {
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           <div class="form-group form-group--xs">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Item2.Email, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Your email address..." })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Item2.Email)
           </div>
           <div class="form-group form-group--xs">
              @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Item2.Message, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Your message...", rows = "4" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Item2.Message)
           </div>

           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-inverse btn-sm btn-block" value="Send Your Message" />
        }
```

The controller is

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<PartialViewResult> Submit([Bind(Prefix = "Item2")] ContactForm model)
        {
            bool isMessageSent = true;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    await Services.EmailService.SendContactForm(model);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    isMessageSent = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isMessageSent = false;
            }
            return PartialView("_SubmitMessage", isMessageSent);
        }
```

and the contact form is

```
 public class ContactForm
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must provide your email."), EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must include a message.")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally the partial view is

```
@model bool

@if (Model)
{
    <div style="color:#c2ff1f">Your message has been sent.</div>
}
else
{
    <div style="color:#f34141">An error occured while sending your message</div>
}
```

**Update:** The rendered html for the email textbox is

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" 
data-val="true" 
data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." 
data-val-required="You must provide your email." 
id="Item2_Email" 
name="Item2.Email" 
placeholder="Your email address..." 
type="text" 
value="">
```

If i do not enter any text in the email field or the message field, the message is not sent :) but i have no validation errors in the view :(
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it would be better if you return a view instead of a partialview. You will get to the screen where it displays that an error occured while sending the email. I think it's enough when you insert "return View();" in the else block of the controller.

Comment: @Larce Changed to public async Task<ViewResult> and return View(model); but it is also not working as expected

Comment: What's happening then? Do you still get to the partial view?

Comment: I mean the validation errors are not displaying, i am not returning the partial view now. I guess something is broken with the tuple ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i need a break. I was missing

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a partialView that doesn't have the validation error message code.

Try this code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<PartialViewResult> Submit([Bind(Prefix = "Item2")] ContactForm model)
        {
            bool isMessageSent = true;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    await Services.EmailService.SendContactForm(model);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    isMessageSent = false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                isMessageSent = false;
                //Return the view that has validation error message display code.
                return View(model);
            }
            return PartialView("_SubmitMessage", isMessageSent);
        }
```

Comment: Hello, can i return both PartialViewResult and ViewResult from the same controller?

Comment: If you are returning actionResult. Yes!

Comment: @OrElse the html in your update, is the code generated prior to hitting submit or after hitting submit (returned with Error) ?

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas We can't return both PartialViewResult and ViewResult from the same controller.

Comment: @ParthRuparelia Why not?

Answer (score 0):

For those people like me just add these scripts to your view:

1. [jquery.validate](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js)
2. [jquery.validate.unobtrusive](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js)